# JSSOR Slider not resizing with orientation flip on Windows Phones and Androids

Tags: responsive-design, slider, device-orientation, jssor, responsive-slides

I have implemented a JSSOR slider into my responsive redesign on my website. You can view it [here](http://www.westshore.edu/responsive/index.html).

At first, I had an issue with the slider responding to an orientation change on iPhones and iPads. Through a little research I found that I had to add a orientationchange command to fix it.

After I got that working I tried doing orientation changes on a Windows phone and an Android phone. The re-sizing does not work on either of these devices.

I thought that the resize command was supposed to take care of it.

The code that I think is the issue is this:

ScaleSlider();

```
        if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Android)/)) {
            $(window).bind('resize', ScaleSlider);
        }
        else {
          $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        }
```

Comment: Please add your Code to the Question where you're thinking the error may be.

Comment: How do you set <meta name="viewport" ...?

Answer (score 0):

What about the following event handling code?

```
    if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Android)/)) {
        $(window).bind('resize', ScaleSlider);
    }

    $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
```

Please also place following code in head tag,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```